# How do I execute/run a .sql file in PostgreSQL 9.2.6 + CentOs

Tags: centos-6, postgresql

I would like to know how to execute a .sql file in PostgreSQL.
I'm using CentOs 6.4.

I have created a database and just need to run a script given to me to create tables.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `psql`:

```
psql -f thefile.sql targetdatabase
```

You may need to specify additional parameters, like username to connect as, host to connect to, etc.

Comment: Hi Craig,
I was successful in running the script using the following command: psql -U username -d database -a -f directory/name of file                                                                                                                                    Thanks,

Answer (score 25):

If you already logged in to database then you can use meta commands like

```
db=# \i or \include filename
```

For more info see [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html)

Comment: This answer was surprisingly hard to find on the Internet!

Answer (score 5):

I am adding this it might be useful who try to execute *.sql place where PostgreSQL server located in a difference place.

```
   psql -h localhost -d userstoreis -U admin -p 5432 -a -q -f /home/jobs/Desktop/resources/postgresql.sql
```

These are the usage of each parameter

```
-h PostgreSQL server IP address
-d database name
-U user name
-p port which PostgreSQL server is listening on
-f path to SQL script
```

then you are prompted to enter the password of the user.

Answer (score 0):

My solution on mac:
I have to use `""` with psql. I ran this with vscode terminal

I learned this from the postgreSQL's `runpsql.sh`

```
"/Library/PostgreSQL/11/bin/psql" -h "localhost" -p "9000" -U "username" "database" -f data.sql
```